# QEMU image format

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, images

I have an image with `.qemu` format. I looked [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images) to see QEMU supported formats but there is no `.qemu`. Is`.qemu` equal to raw?

Thanks

Comment: Contact whoever created the image, to find out what it really is. Or try using the `file` command.

Comment: What do you see in `qemu-img info image.qemu` ?